# fetch request in OnMessageSend event and the add-in (Outlook 365)

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I [configured](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/autolaunch?tabs=xmlmanifest) Outlook 365 to open and send fetch request after email send event. fetch request works in Outlook web version, but it does not work in Outlook 364.

```
              fetch(asyncResultBOParsed.baseURL + "/persons/" + personId + "/notes/WithDocument", {
                headers: {
                  accept: "application/json, text/plain, */*",
                  "accept-language": "ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7",
                  authorization: asyncResultBOParsed.access_token,
                },
                referrerPolicy: "same-origin",
                mode: "cors",
                body: formData,
                method: "POST",
              }).then(function () {
                event.completed({
                  allowEvent: true,
                });
              })
              .catch(function (e) {
                event.completed({
                  allowEvent: false,
                  errorMessage: e.name + " " + e.message,
                });
              });
```

I always get this result. How to debug this? I tried sending post to both localhost and non-localhost endpoints.
[image]

Comment: Whats the full error message?